# Insert multiple words to a String issue

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I want insert multiple words in a String, But **offset is relative to the original String**:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("abcdefghijk");
sb.insert(3,"123");
sb.insert(5,"456");
System.out.println(sb);
```

Result:

```
abc124563defghijk
```

I'd like the Result is:

```
abc123de456fghijk
```

How can I do? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reverse the order of the two inserts, and you'll get the expected result. More generally, start with the larger insertion indices and proceed to the smaller.

It is also worth noting that [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) should be preferred to [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Comment: Great! That's what I want, You're genius!